# Azure: Cannot Configure a VM Size beyond A0-A4

Tags: azure, configure, azure-virtual-machine

I am attempting to increase the size of a Virtual Machine on my Azure subscription from an A2 (2 cores, 3.5GB) machine to a D3 (4 cores, 14GB) machine.  The only options available for this particular VM on the configure tab > Virtual machine size are:
- A0
- A1
- A2
- A3
- A4

I do not see an A5 or a D3 virtual machine size available - although these are available for other virtual machines within my subscription. We have had this and a couple of other VMs with the same issue running for about a year and a half - the newer VMs in our subscription (as well as machines in the create gallery) can all be scaled into the memory and CPU intensive versions (A5 or D3, D4).

Is there any pathway that will allow me to upgrade this older VM to a newer specification of Virtual Machine?

Comment: Do you have the "VIRTUAL MACHINE TIER" (BASIC|STANDARD) switch on the "CONFIGURE" tab?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, in the portal it says "This pricing tier is not available in the selected virtual machine's domain name" even though all I want to do is upgrade to an A5

Comment: It looks like I'm magically able to select A5 instance now... EDIT: nevermind I was able to select it on the portal UI but it failed

Comment: I do in fact have the orginal VM set up in the STANDARD bracket - it looks like Micah's answer below is spot-on.  The machine was created before April 16, 2013.

Strangely enough, when I went to look back at the settings on the machine - the full set is now available.  I now have options from A0 to D14.  Happy Days!  (Something must have happened in the background)!

Answer (score 3):

According to the Azure MSDN article "***Virtual Machine and Cloud Service Sizes for Azure***" at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn197896.aspx
You can't increase the size of a "Basic Tier" VM to larger than A4. So, it looks like you will need to use the "Standard Tier" instead.

If the option to switch to the "Standard Tier" is not available for this VM, the explanation may be that VMs created before "April 16, 2013" may not be able to be upgraded to larger than A4 because of the older datacenter in which they reside. The article includes an explanation of this issue and link to a troubleshooting guide for workarounds for the "***Error: “Failed to configure virtual machine” with A5, A6 or A7 VM size***" at: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9693f56c-fcd3-4d42-850e-5e3b56c7d6be/error-failed-to-configure-virtual-machine-with-a5-a6-or-a7-vm-size?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: Micah has identified what seems to have been the issue: _VMs created before "April 16, 2013" may not be able to be upgraded to larger than A4 because of the older datacenter in which they reside._

I think someone must be pulling some strings in the background, however, as I have logged in this morning, and the full set of A0 through D16 are now available!  Many thanks to whoever may have made the adjustment in the background - and if it is just a very strange coincidence that the VMs showed up today, well, thanks to whoever upgraded that particular rack at this particular time!

Comment: My optimism was premature.  I was able to select the VM size I wanted (D3), but when I attempted to save the configuration, I was provided this message:
_Unable to upgrade the deployment. The requested VM size 'Standard_D3' may not be available in the resources supporting the existing deployment. Please try again later, try with a different VM size or smaller number of role instances, or create a deployment under an empty hosted service with a new affinity group or no affinity group binding._

Answer (score 0):

[This blog article](https://buildwindows.wordpress.com/2015/10/11/azure-virtual-machine-resizing-consideration/) visualizes changeable VM sizes in tables. Note that the blog information could be old, but it shows that there are VM sizes not changeable even though it is selectable on the list.

From the blog, below table gives an answer.

[image]

[image]

Note that above one is "ASM" while below is "ARM".

Changing VM size is strongly (or we can say definitely) depended on the Azure infrastructure, so the only way to resolve the issue is just to create new VM.

Comment: this is old now